# Controlling position of text when positioned

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

I am trying to full width video the [following](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/vgmaxK) code is a example. I don't want to restrict video by giving it a height as it is responsive, but the content or  above positioned over it is pushing down when i view it on small screen e.g. Mobile
How can i make sure the text over the video shows at the same position even when screen is small and the text or panel below it also hide behind or hide/overlap the video.

I want to make the text on video and below be decent and not jumping or hiding. Am i using positions wrong?

```
.centered{
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    z-index: 1;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 10px #000;
}
video{
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: _“where body will be position:relative , so i gave video element position:absolute”_ – why? What does the one thing have to do with the other?

Comment: @CBroe i want the video element to sit left:0 and top:0, so it will be relative to body?

Comment: Why would that need absolute positioning? If you put it as first element into body, then all you need to do is eliminate the default margins/paddings that might get applied via the browser stylesheet.

Comment: @CBroe i forgot to add in my code, but my first element is logo and nav, and below is video. Then content below video height collapse as i don't want to give it height as it is unknown.

Comment: Well if you know the aspect ratio of the video upfront, then you can use what’s called the _padding-bottom hack_.

Comment: @CBroe How? I want something like [this](http://www.joe-san.com/) but my page got text (page content) below the video which overlap video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the parent element has `position: relative;` and contains the video, and the parent adjusts responsively with the video. I do this by getting the aspect ratio of the video and creating padding (56.2%) that creates space for the video's aspect ratio (using the technique from the [iframe section here](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)), then put the text in that parent element and use a combination of `position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to center the text over the video.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

#video {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.2%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#video video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#video h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="video">
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="">
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <h1>We Evolve with our students
</div>
```

Comment: My text in my case a glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle will not align, rather reposition itself according to screen on position top basis, your seem to be working fine. Is it because of text vs glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle is a icon?

Comment: @Nofel I'm not sure what you mean. Can you show me?

Comment: I created a new post with my [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841065/video-wont-play-after-first-time-playing)

Answer (score 1):

I think this [link](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) will help you about centring anything ;)
About positioning text, you can use `vh` value. Ie.

```
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30vh
}
```

Also, [this guy from the top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41812869/3012785) have a good example about absolute positioning ;)

[Link](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) about `vh`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css for the div with centerred class. Hope this will help you.
change the position to **absolute** and use the **calc function** to position the text to center from **top**

```
.centered 
{
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(100% - 50%);
 text-align : center; 
 left : 0;
 right : 0;
 z-index: 1;
 color:#fff;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 10px #000;
}
```